# On a CSS hover event can I change another div's styling with fade?

Tags: css, image, background, hover, fade

I look a background image on hover of a button like this:

```
    $(function() {
      $('#a').hover(function() {
        $('.conte`enter code here`nitoreindex').css('background', 'url(immagini/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center');
      }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the background colour
        $('.contenitoreindex').css('background', '');
      });
    });
```

There is no way to color the second element with a slow fade?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$('.contenitoreindex').fadeout("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $(this).css('background', '');
})
```

Comment: $(function() {
  $('#safety').hover(function() {
    
 $('.contenitoreindex').fadeout("slow", function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'url(immagini/safetyindex.jpg) no-repeat center center');
   });
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.contenitoreindex').css('background', '');
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

The css property background is a shorthand for setting background-image.
and this is hard to animate since then you would have to put in an other image.

but you can animate the opacity of the element? So that it fades in. (all text and other content to)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a').hover(function() {
    $('#b').css('background', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) no-repeat center center');
    $('#b').animate({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#a {
  height: 50px;
}
#b {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a">hover
</span>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: I wish the animation there is on Hover, not on MouseOut. (sorry for my english)

Comment: you want the image to fade into view?

Answer (score 0):

I almost wish that hover on a button to change the background image of your container div.